# Python/Selenium - Site is detecting I am using driver and blocking access

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python 2.7 and Selenium driver for Chrome. I have done lot of automation with various websites, which include iFrame/login/OTP etc i.e to say I know my way around these things.

Now, I am stuck with one case where stock broker website uses some sort of bot detection (I am guessing) when I open a Chrome via selenium driver, even if I click around (to ensure cookies and other variable are set) and then manually login using the user id and password - it fails to authenticate me (show a message "Invalid login ID or password")

Is there anyway around this? (circumvent driver detection)? or is this something else?

I tried searching the site's javascripts/html source to see any clues for such thing, but I don't see anything like that.

Any help is very much appreciated, I am using this automation for **my personal use** and not to cause any stress on those target systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `undetected selenium` driver.

It's implemented to avoid CloudFlare / Captcha / scenarios for bot detection.
It doesn't work for every case, but it can pass most of bot detection checks.

(Be aware that you need to upgrade Python to `3.6+`)

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from undetected_chromedriver import ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions() # your options
driver = uc.Chrome(options)
```

[Reference](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't go for 3.6+ 

But finally I ended up with this solution 

username = os.getenv("USERNAME")
userProfile = "C:\\Users\\" + username +
    "\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir={}".format(userProfile))

from here : "https://stackoverflow.com/a/33396684"